# CSS stop working after change device orientation

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm designing a responsive website and after change my cellphone orientation from portrait to landscape and then to portrait the CSS stop working.

Initially the css that I apply to the the 320-480 resolution loads very well in my portrait screen and also in the landscape but when I change it back to portrait the css stop working, is like is not loading the css.

What's the problem????

Comment: How are we supposed to know without the code or what phone it is?

Comment: I thought it was a common problem in mobile devices,

Comment: Well… no. Never seen it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using css media queries it is unnecessary to assign a min width, you can use simply max width and have multiple queries if you want the layout to change at a different point. I can't explain why your css works initially but then changes when you turn the screen a couple times but here is some good css media query practice and syntax that could solve your problem:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px){
    /*Some css styling for widths below 320 pixels*/
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    /*Some css styling for widths below 480 pixels.
    Keep in mind that this css will only be applied for viewports between 320
    pixels and 480 pixels*/
}
```

It is not necessary to use **device-width** when you can simply use **width**. Also the **'only screen and()'** is good practice for detecting mobile viewport widths in css. I hope that this helps and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The css

```
@media all and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px){
    #reviews{
        display: none !important;
    }
    .footer {  
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC !important;   
    }
    ul,ol{
        margin-left: 0px!important; 
    }
    .bottom-menu ul{
        margin-left: 25px !important;
    }
    #side-quote{
        display: none;
    }
    #export-dption{
        float: bottom;
    }
    #export-request{
        float: top;
    }
    .panoramic-pic{
        padding: 0px !important;
    }
    #googleMap{
        display: none;
    }
    .quote-index{
        width: 100% !important;
        background: red !important;
    }
}
```

and the cellphone is a LG Optimus F3 and the browser is chrome.

as you can see in the selector .quote-index is set the background to red, initially it loads in red when the phone is in portrait mode but when i change it to landscape an then back to portrait is like that selector doens't exits.

Comment: You can edit your questions and add this code to the actual question. Answers should be answers.